# Why doesn't a Promise that modifies an Angular component error when resolved after the component's destruction?

Tags: javascript, angular, es6-promise

I am creating a Promise within an Angular (5.x) component that, after 10 seconds, modifies the component's state, then resolves.

As a test, I am ensuring that the component is "destroyed" before 10 seconds elapse. (I'm doing this by navigating away from the component's route.) In so doing, I expect the Promise's resolution to generate an error — *since it modifies the component's state*.

But it doesn't. I'm trying to understand why.

Here are the relevant parts of the component:

```
private _foo: string;

ngOnInit() {
    this._foo = 'foo';

    let aPromiseThatSeemsDoomedToError = new Promise<boolean>((resolve) => {
        setTimeout(() => {this._test(); resolve(true);}, 10000);
    });
}

ngOnDestroy() {
    console.warn('TestComponent destroyed');
}


private _test():void {
    this._foo = 'bar';
    console.warn('_test() called! _foo is:', this._foo);
}
```

The console output looks like this:

```
// Triggered by routing way from the component
NavComponent destroyed
// 10 seconds after component creation
test called! _foo is: bar
```

I've received different kinds of asynchronous errors after component destruction, for example with `setTimeout()`s and Observable subscriptions that weren't cleaned up during `ngOnDestroy()`.

So, why is this Promise code working even after the component is destroyed?

Comment: The promise doesn't get destroyed when the component is destroyed.

Comment: But the Promise modifies the component's internal state. That's why I expect an error.

Comment: The object is not destroyed from memory. Angular stops referencing the component, but it stays in the JavaScript memory.

Comment: Okay, that begins to clarify it for me… I'm still not sure why this kind of interacting with "destroyed" Angular components is fine when others I've encountered are not. But that's probably a different question, or anyway it requires more information.